# Video Streaming with Kurento

Tags: video-streaming, kurento

I have a Java app and I'm running Kurento Media Server on a Linux machine.I am trying to get the app running. I can access the webpage, see the local stream working, but the remote stream never comes through -- on either Chrome or Firefox.

The log

The webpage console reads:

```
10:24:54.361 [  http-nio-80-exec-7] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.CallHandler       - Incoming message from user 'Alex': {"id":"receiveVideoFrom","sender":"Alex","sdpOffer":"v=0\r\no=- 3371483860$
10:24:54.362 [  http-nio-80-exec-7] INFO  - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.UserSession       - USER Alex: connecting with Alex in room myroom
10:24:54.362 [  http-nio-80-exec-7] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.UserSession       - PARTICIPANT Alex: configuring loopback
10:24:54.363 [  http-nio-80-exec-7] DEBUG - o.k.c.i.c.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler  - Invoking method public abstract java.lang.String org.kurento.client.SdpEndpoint.processOffer(java.lang.String$
10:24:54.378 [  http-nio-80-exec-7] DEBUG - o.k.j.client.JsonRpcClientWebSocket      - Req-> {"id":3,"method":"invoke","params":{"object":"23f96b3d-fb8f-48f8-a009-14efec6e93be_MediaPipeline/1b9ed8$
10:24:54.711 [  http-nio-80-exec-7] DEBUG - o.k.j.client.JsonRpcClientWebSocket      - <-Res {"id":3,"result":{"value":"v=0\r\no=- 3371483860089944829 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=Kurento Media Server\r\$
10:24:54.712 [  http-nio-80-exec-7] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.UserSession       - USER Alex: Sending message {"id":"receiveVideoAnswer","name":"Alex","sdpAnswer":"v=0\r\no=- 33714838600899448$
10:24:59.107 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.CallHandler       - Incoming message from new user: {"id":"joinRoom","name":"Alex","room":"559a3b4683c8c"}
10:24:59.108 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] INFO  - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.CallHandler       - PARTICIPANT Alex: trying to join room 559a3b4683c8c
10:24:59.108 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.RoomManager       - Searching for room 559a3b4683c8c
10:24:59.108 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.RoomManager       - Room 559a3b4683c8c not existent. Will create now!
10:24:59.108 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.j.client.JsonRpcClientWebSocket      - Req-> {"id":4,"method":"create","params":{"type":"MediaPipeline","constructorParams":{},"sessionId":"d25998a6$
10:24:59.111 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.j.client.JsonRpcClientWebSocket      - <-Res {"id":4,"result":{"value":"8f687144-a7ac-41fc-8e8e-da8c52617786_MediaPipeline","sessionId":"d25998a6-86$
10:24:59.112 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] INFO  - org.kurento.tutorial.groupcall.Room      - ROOM 559a3b4683c8c has been created
10:24:59.112 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.RoomManager       - Room 559a3b4683c8c found!
10:24:59.112 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] INFO  - org.kurento.tutorial.groupcall.Room      - ROOM Alex: adding participant Alex
10:24:59.112 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.j.client.JsonRpcClientWebSocket      - Req-> {"id":5,"method":"create","params":{"type":"WebRtcEndpoint","constructorParams":{"mediaPipeline":"8f687$
10:24:59.115 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.j.client.JsonRpcClientWebSocket      - <-Res {"id":5,"result":{"value":"8f687144-a7ac-41fc-8e8e-da8c52617786_MediaPipeline/baa692bd-f82d-4714-9ac9-a$
10:24:59.115 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - org.kurento.tutorial.groupcall.Room      - ROOM 559a3b4683c8c: notifying other participants of new participant Alex
10:24:59.116 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - org.kurento.tutorial.groupcall.Room      - PARTICIPANT Alex: sending a list of 0 participants
10:24:59.116 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.UserSession       - USER Alex: Sending message {"id":"existingParticipants","data":[]}
10:24:59.117 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.CallHandler       - Incoming message from user 'Alex': {"id":"leaveRoom"}
10:24:59.117 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.RoomManager       - Searching for room 559a3b4683c8c
10:24:59.117 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.RoomManager       - Room 559a3b4683c8c found!
10:24:59.117 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - org.kurento.tutorial.groupcall.Room      - PARTICIPANT Alex: Leaving room 559a3b4683c8c
10:24:59.117 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - org.kurento.tutorial.groupcall.Room      - ROOM 559a3b4683c8c: notifying all users that Alex is leaving the room
10:24:59.117 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.UserSession       - PARTICIPANT Alex: Releasing resources
10:24:59.118 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.c.i.c.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler  - Invoking method public abstract void org.kurento.client.KurentoObject.release(org.kurento.client.Continuation$
10:24:59.122 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - o.k.c.i.c.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler  - Invoking method public abstract void org.kurento.client.KurentoObject.release(org.kurento.client.Continuation$
10:24:59.123 [     pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG - o.k.j.client.JsonRpcClientWebSocket      - Req-> {"id":6,"method":"release","params":{"object":"8f687144-a7ac-41fc-8e8e-da8c52617786_MediaPipeline/baa69$
10:24:59.127 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] DEBUG - org.kurento.tutorial.groupcall.Room      - Room 559a3b4683c8c closed
10:24:59.128 [  http-nio-80-exec-8] INFO  - o.k.tutorial.groupcall.RoomManager       - Room 559a3b4683c8c removed and closed
```

I don't know if the video is not passing because is a problem of open ports.

And if I am trying to do the Hello World app I get the following

```
Loading complete ...
Starting video call ...
spec: {"audio":true,"video":{"mandatory":{"maxWidth":640,"maxFrameRate":15,"minFrameRate":15}}}
chrome: {"audio":true,"video":{"mandatory":{"maxWidth":640,"maxFrameRate":15,"minFrameRate":15}}}
Created SDP offer
Local description set
ICE negotiation completed
Invoking SDP offer callback function 10.5.104.13
Received sdpAnswer from server. Processing ...
SDP answer received, setting remote description
```

Anybody, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are your clients and your KMS server in the same network? If not, you'll need to use a STUN server.

Comment: I'm facing now similar problem as you Amrida D, my last log is equal to your -> 'SDP answer received, setting remote description', have you found any solution?

Comment: Ok we have found a root cause of this problem internally. Security policies of my company doesn't allow to go through in/out a stream which was sent with WebRTC.